# Ursina - Custom model refuses to be textured

Tags: python, 3d, ursina

I'm using Ursina in Python 3.8

I have a custom model that I made for an entity. I have a texture for that model, exported from my 3D modeling tool as a .png image. I tried applying the texture like this:
`Entity(model='monolith', scale=0.2, name='monolith', position=(50,0,100), collider='mesh', color=color.dark_gray, texture='/models/monolith')`

In-game, the model is just solid black. I tried this with a different model, same result - nothing with a custom model is showing its texture.

How can I get Ursina to texture my custom models?

For this specific example, I'm using a .obj file, but I've seen this issue with .fbx, .glb, and .stl 3D objects
If it helps to know, I made my 3D model with [this online tool](https://app.vectary.com/).

Complete code:

```
from classes.constants import *
fsmode = getinput("Fullscreen? [Y/N] > ")

if (fsmode == "Y"):fsmode = True
else:fsmode = False

import time as systime, socket, socketserver, random
from ursina import *
import ursina.audio as audio
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from ursina.prefabs.health_bar import HealthBar
from ursina.shaders import *
from threading import Thread as thread

from classes.class_override import *
from classes.custom_classes import *

grav=1
player_model = "/models/player"
pcolor = color.rgb(185, 185, 135)
remoteplayer_color = color.rgb(145, 185, 145)
remoteplayer_disconnected = color.rgb(25,25,25,25)
stored_camera_y = 0
duty_cycle=0
remote_player_connected = False
r_player_justconnected = False
paused = False
block_outgoing_updates = False

app = Ursina(development_mode=False, show_ursina_splash_screen=True,fullscreen=fsmode,title="Reality Simulator (now with Portals!)")

random.seed(0)
Entity.default_shader = lit_with_shadows_shader

ground = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground")
ground2 = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground", position=(128,0,128))
ground_brick = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground", position=(0,0,128))
ground_brick2 = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground", position=(128,0,0))
spawning_platform = Entity(model='cube', collider='box', scale=(3,0.5,3), texture='brick', position=(0,0,-10))

editor_camera = EditorCamera(enabled=False, ignore_paused=True, move_speed=30)

player = FirstPersonController(model=player_model, z=-10, y=0.5, color=pcolor, origin_y=0.12, gravity=grav, speed=8, jump_height = 4, height=3, collider='mesh', name="player", cursor=Entity(parent=camera.ui, model='quad', color=color.pink, scale=.001, rotation_z=45))
# player_healthbar = HealthBar(max_value=player.max_hp, animation_duration=0.1, value=player.max_hp, parent=camera.ui)
p2 = Entity(model=player_model, color=remoteplayer_disconnected, scale=1, name='remote_player', x=-5,y=0,z=-5, rotation_y=180)
# sim_symbol = Entity(model='diamond', collider='mesh', color=color.green, name='sim_symbol', parent=player, position=(0,6,0), scale=(.5,1,.5), visible=False)
player.visible_self = False
# player = FirstPersonController(model=player_model, z=-10, color=color.orange, origin_y=-.5, speed=8)
# player.collider = MeshCollider(player, Vec3(0,1,0), Vec3(1,2,1))

arm = Entity(model='portal_gun_2', parent=camera, position=(.5,-.25,0.45), scale=.004, origin_z=-.5, rotation_z=0, on_cooldown=False, name="gun", color=pcolor, texture='/textures/w_portalgun.png')
portal_gun_showcase = Entity(model=('portal_gun.fbx'), position=(25,2,-5), scale=.05, origin_z=-.5, rotation_z=0, on_cooldown=False, name="pgun_showcase", collider='box', texture=('/textures/w_portalgun.png'))

def genstairs():
    stairs(128,0.3,7,30)

thread(name="stair_gen", target=genstairs).start()

def update():
    global player, stored_camera_y, duty_cycle
    duty_cycle += 1

    if (block_outgoing_updates):
        arm.color=color.rgb(25,25,25,25)
    else:
        arm.color=pcolor

    if held_keys['escape']:
        os.abort()

    if held_keys['x']:
        player.y += 10

    if (held_keys['left shift'] and not held_keys['control']):
        player.speed = player.sprint_speed
    elif (player.speed == player.sprint_speed):player.speed=8

    if player.get_position()[1] < -20:
        prot = player.rotation
        destroy(player)
        player = FirstPersonController(model=player_model, z=-10, color=pcolor, speed=8, rotation=prot, origin_y=0.12, gravity=grav, jump_height = 4, height=3, collider='mesh', name=player_model)
        player.visible_self = False
        print("info: player reset")

mouse.visible = False
mouse.locked = True
app.run()
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Tanay, yes I can. I'll trim it down a bit so it's not impossible to read :)

Comment: Can you try `gun_entity.flip_faces()` ? Tell me if it works

Comment: I'm legitimately astonished... it didn't work before, with any of my other models... but it works for this one! I even tried this before and it didn't work, I guess you're just magical. Thank you!

Comment: If you problem is solved please mark my answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Entity.flip_faces()` function in ursina after adding this you code will look like this:

```
from classes.constants import *
fsmode = getinput("Fullscreen? [Y/N] > ")

if (fsmode == "Y"):fsmode = True
else:fsmode = False

import time as systime, socket, socketserver, random
from ursina import *
import ursina.audio as audio
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from ursina.prefabs.health_bar import HealthBar
from ursina.shaders import *
from threading import Thread as thread

from classes.class_override import *
from classes.custom_classes import *

grav=1
player_model = "/models/player"
pcolor = color.rgb(185, 185, 135)
remoteplayer_color = color.rgb(145, 185, 145)
remoteplayer_disconnected = color.rgb(25,25,25,25)
stored_camera_y = 0
duty_cycle=0
remote_player_connected = False
r_player_justconnected = False
paused = False
block_outgoing_updates = False

app = Ursina(development_mode=False, show_ursina_splash_screen=True,fullscreen=fsmode,title="Reality Simulator (now with Portals!)")

random.seed(0)
Entity.default_shader = lit_with_shadows_shader

ground = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground")
ground2 = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground", position=(128,0,128))
ground_brick = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground", position=(0,0,128))
ground_brick2 = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=128, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4), name="ground", position=(128,0,0))
spawning_platform = Entity(model='cube', collider='box', scale=(3,0.5,3), texture='brick', position=(0,0,-10))

editor_camera = EditorCamera(enabled=False, ignore_paused=True, move_speed=30)

player = FirstPersonController(model=player_model, z=-10, y=0.5, color=pcolor, origin_y=0.12, gravity=grav, speed=8, jump_height = 4, height=3, collider='mesh', name="player", cursor=Entity(parent=camera.ui, model='quad', color=color.pink, scale=.001, rotation_z=45))
# player_healthbar = HealthBar(max_value=player.max_hp, animation_duration=0.1, value=player.max_hp, parent=camera.ui)
p2 = Entity(model=player_model, color=remoteplayer_disconnected, scale=1, name='remote_player', x=-5,y=0,z=-5, rotation_y=180)
# sim_symbol = Entity(model='diamond', collider='mesh', color=color.green, name='sim_symbol', parent=player, position=(0,6,0), scale=(.5,1,.5), visible=False)
player.visible_self = False
# player = FirstPersonController(model=player_model, z=-10, color=color.orange, origin_y=-.5, speed=8)
# player.collider = MeshCollider(player, Vec3(0,1,0), Vec3(1,2,1))

arm = Entity(model='portal_gun_2', parent=camera, position=(.5,-.25,0.45), scale=.004, origin_z=-.5, rotation_z=0, on_cooldown=False, name="gun", color=pcolor, texture='/textures/w_portalgun.png')
portal_gun_showcase = Entity(model=('portal_gun.fbx'), position=(25,2,-5), scale=.05, origin_z=-.5, rotation_z=0, on_cooldown=False, name="pgun_showcase", collider='box', texture=('/textures/w_portalgun.png'))

arm.flip_faces()
portal_gun_showcase.flip_faces()

def genstairs():
    stairs(128,0.3,7,30)

thread(name="stair_gen", target=genstairs).start()

def update():
    global player, stored_camera_y, duty_cycle
    duty_cycle += 1

    if (block_outgoing_updates):
        arm.color=color.rgb(25,25,25,25)
    else:
        arm.color=pcolor

    if held_keys['escape']:
        os.abort()

    if held_keys['x']:
        player.y += 10

    if (held_keys['left shift'] and not held_keys['control']):
        player.speed = player.sprint_speed
    elif (player.speed == player.sprint_speed):player.speed=8

    if player.get_position()[1] < -20:
        prot = player.rotation
        destroy(player)
        player = FirstPersonController(model=player_model, z=-10, color=pcolor, speed=8, rotation=prot, origin_y=0.12, gravity=grav, jump_height = 4, height=3, collider='mesh', name=player_model)
        player.visible_self = False
        print("info: player reset")

mouse.visible = False
mouse.locked = True
app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Flipping the faces worked, somehow