# Ursina not loading texture on model

Tags: python, textures, panda3d, ursina

I'm trying to import a model I found online, I've looked on YouTube and everywhere else with no luck...

here's the model: https://skfb.ly/SyXJ

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
from ursina import load_texture
window.title = 'ursina'
camera.orthographic = True
camera.fov = 2.5
bmwtexture = load_texture('my_image.jpg')

e36 = Entity(model = 'bmw', texture = bmwtexture, scale=(0.05, 0.05, 0.05))
app.run()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIZBd.jpg

Im planning on using this in a project of mine with sensors and the sort and I really need to see what Im doing.
Im pretty new to ursina but I can't fathom what I'm missing.

it could be about the jpg and SRGB but not sure. maybe because i'm on a Mac.

edit: ive tried running the program on my windows machine with no luck... it has to be something to do with the SRGB profile... right?

edit: ok to I've reinstalled everything since I was having a few bugs installing things, still doesn't work... i'm going to try and look into this SRGB thing.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437439/ursina-custom-model-refuses-to-be-textured)

Comment: Try `entity.flip_faces()` on the entity you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine when you change model to cube:

```py
e36 = Entity(model = 'cube', texture = bmwtexture, scale=(0.05, 0.05, 0.05))
```

So maibe the texture doesn't apper in the visible areas of the model?

Answer (score 1):

Loading a texture using load_texture() can often be a pain. Try just doing this:

```
e36 = Entity(model = 'bmw', texture = "my_image.jpg", scale = (0.05, 0.05, 0.05))
```

Also, I use a Mac and haven't come across any problems except when it comes to shaders.