# why and how to fix ursina texture doesn't work and model pure dark black?

Tags: python, model, 3d, textures, ursina

[image]

The texture works well on another .obj:

[image]

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72462905/17675859) answer. Try to do ```Entity.flip_faces()```